# Make transparent text with drop shadow with Affinity Designer

Tags: text, transparency, effects, affinity-designer

I'm trying to make transparent text with a drop shadow in Affinity Designer. So far I have had no luck.

I want the end result to be similar to this. (It's hard to tell, but the text *is* transparent)

[image: Transparent text with drop shadow]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, so I finally figured out how to do this.

1. Write the text
2. Apply an Outer Shadow FX
3. Still in the Layer Effects dialog, set the Fill Opacity (on bottom right) to 0%

[image]